# Create Firebase Dynamic Link using JAVA

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, spring-mvc, firebase-dynamic-links

In my firebase account, I create dynamic link manually and I got that dynamic link in my application, but the issue is that I need to create dynamic link randomly using JAVA.

I am able to create manually, but not able to create using JAVA.

Comment: Do you encounter any error message upon setting up dynamic link using Java? Could you share it here?